# Where to find the admin console of RAD 8 (based on Eclipse)?

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

How can I open the Admin Console of WAS 8 that is built in with IBM RAD 8?

Comment: Does the server not have a right-click, Administration > Run Administrative Console? My WAS 6.1 in RAD 8 does, but I don't have a WAS 8 right now to compare with.

Comment: @dbreaux Thank you for the answer, I think that is it. I'm still just learning WAS 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the server --> Administration --> Run Administrative Console

Comment: It is same in WAS 9 also